# Trouble Plotting Function

Tags: plotting

[image]

I'm trying to plot some simple functions and the graphs aren't appearing. Is it something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Try `Sine1[x_]:=2*Sin...`

Answer (score 2):

Just to facilitate:

```
fa = 2 Sin[2 Pi x/3];
fb[x_] := fa;
fc = Function[x, fa];
fd = 2 Sin[2 Pi #/3] &;
Plot[fa, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
Plot[fb[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
Plot[fc[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
Plot[fd[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

I suggest running this in a clean kernel.  Look at differences. The documentation is very helpful and I suggest searching this site. Also you may wish to search `Evaluate` and  `Plot` questions which covers an important common problem with plotting failures.